# Using JQuery with a string (instead of DOM)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I remember using a plugin in the past where I could use AJax to load a page and update only part of the DOM. The AJax request returns the entire HTML page, but only a small portion of it replaces part of the currently loaded DOM.

For example, SO can use this function to fetch `http://stackoverflow.com` and only update `#content`. SO would make an AJax request to fetch `http://stackoverflow.com`, fetch `#content` from the returned string, and update `#content` of the DOM.

Sorry if my question is confusing. How would I do this without a plugin?

Comment: Your question is not very clear, or I'm having a problem understanding it. "How would I do this without a plugin?" What does "this" refer to? What you were referring to in your example is the `$.fn.load` method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) function is designed to do this. Just include a selector for an element along with the URL, like so:

```
$('#content').load('http://stackoverflow.com #content', optionalCallbackFunction);
```

That will replace the content of the element with ID `content` on the current page, with the contents of the element with ID `content` on the page returned by an AJAX request to `http://stackoverflow.com`, then run the function called `optionalCallbackFunction`. Assuming, of course, that the request was successful.

Comment: So `$('some element to replace the content of')` is probably `$('#content')`.

Comment: yes - ajax.load is your main option here. Refer to this link full the details: http://api.jquery.com/load/. It includes the full description of how to load portion of the page as highlighted by Anthony above.

Comment: The only thing I don't like about the `.load()` method is that it actually loads the whole page first and then it gets the content from the specific section with `id="#content"` in this case. It is pretty much like having a hidden inline content.

Comment: @JFK I see your point, though I can't think of any way to avoid loading the entire page in a purely Javascript solution.

Answer (score 0):

Without the AJAX, you can parse a raw string like this:

```
var str = "<div><h1>Page Title</h1><div id='content'>This is new.</div></div>";
var text = $("#content",$(str)).html();
$('#content').html(text);
```